# I want to take input from user of url in python

Tags: python-3.x, url

I want to take website name from user input and maximum no. of pages that he want to crawl for crawling website...but can't getting any solution..here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import *
from urllib import request


url1 = input("Enter url you want to crawl:")
max_pages1 = int(input("Enter no. of pages you want to crawl:"))


def web_crawler(max_pages,url):
   page = 1
   while page <= max_pages:
      url4 = str(url) + str(page)
      url_get = requests.get(url4)
      plain_text = url_get.text
      soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")
      for a in soup.findAll('a',{'rel':'bookmark'}):
          href = a.get('href')
          title = a.string
          #print(title)
          print(href)
          #info_about_web_pages(href)
      page +=1

def info_about_web_pages(url):
   url_get = requests.get(url)
   plain_text = url_get.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser" )
   links = set()
   for about in soup.findAll('a'):
       href = about.get('href')
       links.update([href])

   print(links)

web_crawler(max_pages1,url1)
```

It shows me nothing in output

Comment: do you have an example of the url you are trying to do this for?  Are you sure that an anchor with the attribute 'rel': 'bookmark' is in its source code?

Comment: Yes url is in rel:bookmark.... .. url is http://www.fonearena.com/blog/

Answer (score 1):

If there is no anchor with the attributes you are trying to find in the html source code then this will always print nothing.  try printing soup.prettify() and see if the tag you are looking for even exists.  More often than not when I am not printing the values I'm expecting it's because the value does not have the attributes I am looking for.

Comment: in the line after `soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser" )` put `print(str(soup.prettify()))`